# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Пытаюсь реализовать `TodoList` с помощью `mobx 6` без декораторов. Описал класс `TodoStore`. Но при активации метода addTodo мне выдает ошибку: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined`. Не понимаю, в чем дело. Я определил `tasks` как `any[] = [];`

Мой стор:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';
    
export class TodoStore {

    private tasks: any[] = [];
    
    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    get getAllTasks() {
        return this.tasks;
    }

    addTodo(e: any, task: string): void {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.tasks.push({ task });
        console.log(task);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потерял контекст в addTodo добавь стрелочную функцию или this.addTodo() в конструктор